# calling server method in client .net SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm a beginner in SignalR. how can I define method in client, and call it from server. here is my code :

in Server :

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void ServerMethod()
        {
            Clients.All.ClientMethod();
        }
    }
```

in Client :

```
    HubConnection connection;
    IHubProxy proxy;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection = new HubConnection("LocalHostDomain");
        proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
    }

    private void Call_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        proxy.Invoke("ServerMethod");
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        proxy.On("ClientMethod", () =>
        {
            tb1.Text = "Hello";
        });
        connection.Start().Wait();
    }
```

but tb1.Text won't change!! it's very simple, but I don't know how to do it!

Comment: The callback will probably not run on the UI thread, so you might need to synchronize access there. Did you set a breakpoint to check whether you're entering the callback?

Comment: Clients.All.ClientMethod(); will run, Start_Click run without problems, and Call_Click run , but after proxy.Invoke("ServerMethod"); it gives me exception right in tb1.Text = "Hello"; and tells me :  The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. but I think it because of debugging mode. is my code is the right way to do SignalR?

Answer (score 0):

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

SignalR processes the incomming messages in another thread than the UI thread. Changes to the UI *must* always be performed on the UI thread. Therefore, you need to synchronize access. For example:

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  proxy.On("ClientMethod", () => UpdateLabel());
  connection.Start().Wait();
}

private void UpdateLabel()
{
  if (InvokeRequired)
  {
    BeginInvoke(new Action(UpdateLabel));
    return;
  }

  tb1.Text = "Hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do it

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    proxy.On("ClientMethod", () =>
    {
        change_text("Hello");
    });

}
private void change_text(string text)
    {
       if (tb1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            tb1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { tb1.Text = text; }));
        }
        else
        {
            tb1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

you can change the text without having to put it a method. I am just giving you and idea how to do it.